# How to make a character array of size 1000000000000

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

Since I am new to the programming field and I was trying to make a character array of very large size say for example `1000000000000` but my compiler is showing error:

> Array too large

I am using turbo c++.

Can anyone please tell me how to do that?

Comment: If you have a computer with room for an array of 1 terabyte, you really should use a better compiler than turbo c++

Comment: What error? Post your code ([mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: A terabyte in Turbo C++ isn't going to happen. (Why would you want to do that? Do you have any idea how much that is?)

Comment: Curiousity: why do you want to create such a large array in memory?

Comment: More than 1TB??? Memory allocates on RAM..what is the RAM capacity??

Comment: To reduce huge memory allocation one should check his problem whether it is required or not. There must be an alternative way to solve this problem with lesser memory... Can you please share what is the problem you need to fix with this gigantic memory...

Comment: Turbo C++ is a legacy compiler built for 16 bit processors.

Comment: Surely this question is a joke.

Comment: @MatthewJamesBriggs what if it is not? Oh... [the horror... the horror](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKcAYMb5uk4)

Comment: Lilah has a string  sof lowercase English letters that she repeated infinitely many times.

Given an integer n find and print the number of letter a's in the first letters of Lilah's infinite string.

Sample Input 1

a
1000000000000

Sample Output 1

1000000000000

Explanation 1
Because all of the first letters of the infinite string are a, we print on a new line.

Comment: I have posted part of the question I think now someone could help

Comment: You don't have to create infinite string of repeated `s` string. Count how many 'a' inside `s`, and calculate how many time `s` is repeated inside `n` characters and you will find how many 'a' you have (be careful: last repeated `s` is maybe not full)

Comment: Right.  So there is no need to allocate a string anything like that large.  You are supposed to find a slightly less naive algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems:

Firstly Turbo-C++ is a 16-bit compiler, and even with the best will in the world, it is not going to be able to cope.  Even a 32-bit compiler (maximum address space just over 4,000,000,000  bytes) won't be able to cope.  You need to use a 64-bit compiler.

Your next problem is that if you try to allocate such an *enormous* array on the stack, it won't fit.  Most systems use a stack of around 1MB.  You need to allocate the array on the heap.  I normally(*) I would recommend using `std::vector` (because it manages releasing the memory for you).  So instead of:

```
char big[1000ull*1000*1000*1000];
```

You need:

```
std::vector<char> big(1000ull*1000*1000*1000);
```

Your final problem is that very few machines are going to have 1TB of RAM installed.  On Windows 10 you can allocate that much address space - but most of it is going to be in the swap, not in RAM.

*: This is why I wouldn't recommend `std::vector` here.  Something involving either memory mapped files, or a more efficient data structure is going to be better.  We can't tell what, unless you explain your actual problem.